# Symfony error on dev environment: Non existant service "C" (linked to webpack-dev-server)

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, webpack-dev-server, symfony4

I made a Symfony 4 application with webpack dev server for dev environment.

When I use the `bin/console cache:clear` command or go on the app via a browser, I get an error which tells me that I request an non existant service called "C".

I think the error is linked to the routing of the assets.
The error is launch when my dev server isn't running and sometimes even if it is. 
But if I remove the `strict_requirements: true` in routing.yaml the error won't appear.

#### webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    public: 'dev.myapp.io:8080',
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000,
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    compress: true,
    noInfo: true,
    quiet: true,
    port: devServerPort,
}
```

#### config/packages/dev/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    router: { resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/config/packages/dev/routing.yaml' }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
    assets:
        base_urls: 'http://localhost:8080'
        json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/dist/manifest.json'
```

#### config/packages/dev/routing.yaml

```
framework:
    router:
        strict_requirements: true
```

#### The error

```
In Container.php line 277:
You have requested a non-existent service "C". Did you mean one of these: 
"MyApp\Controller\Home\HomeController", 
"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController", 
"Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController"?
```

If someone knows how to avoid the error, I'll be grateful :)
I'd like to keep the `strict_requirements` to true but I don't have other solutions for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error surfaces when when the config's are duplicated across files. So for instance, if in your config/packages/framework.yaml you have

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    router:
      resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
      strict_requirements: ~
```

and then you have in

```
# config/packages/routing.yaml
framework:
    router:
#        strict_requirements: ~
        utf8: true
```

you might get the error you posted. You cannot duplicate config over multiple files. Either remove the routing.yaml file or remove `router` key from `config/packages/framework.yaml`

Hope it helps.